# In Emacs, how to insert file name in shell-command?

Tags: emacs

I use shell-command a lots (default binded to M-!), but often I'm doing stuff to the buffer I'm currently editing. Instead of typing the buffer name (and no filename completion is available in shell-command, alas!), it'd be nice to have a shortcut key, say f3, to insert that name for me whenever I press the key.

The problem is I don't want to bind the key globally (I use f3 for other things in other context), only in minibuffer when shell-command is prompting. It's easy to write a lisp function to insert the current buffer name, but what mode's keymap should I modify to bind a key to that function?

Alternatively, is there any lisp code/package that provide filename completion in shell-command, similar to how bash does it? I know the normal M-x shell does completion, but the convenience of entering a command in minibuffer is hard to give up ;)

**Edit:**

here is what I wanted, taken from [huaiyuan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455345/in-emacs-how-to-insert-file-name-in-shell-command#455368)'s answer with some fixes inspired by / stolen from http://osdir.com/ml/emacs.sources/2002-04/msg00022.html

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map
  [f3] (lambda () (interactive) 
       (insert (buffer-name (current-buffer-not-mini)))))

(defun current-buffer-not-mini ()
  "Return current-buffer if current buffer is not the *mini-buffer*
  else return buffer before minibuf is activated."
  (if (not (window-minibuffer-p)) (current-buffer)
      (if (eq (get-lru-window) (next-window))
          (window-buffer (previous-window)) (window-buffer (next-window)))))
```

Comment: See also: [Is there a user interface in Emacs allowing one to “grab” the buffer's filename conveniently?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9738/4319)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map
  [f3] (lambda () (interactive) (insert (buffer-name))))
```

#### Edit:

As pointed out in the comment section and elsewhere, the above code snippet doesn't work.  (Sorry, I should have tested it before posting. :)  Some fixes have been posted; here is another:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [f3]
  (lambda () (interactive) 
     (insert (buffer-name (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))))))
```

Regarding filename completion while issuing `shell-command`, perhaps this kludge would work (it works for me on Emacs 23.0.60):

```
(require 'shell)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-i") 'comint-dynamic-complete)
```

Comment: That ALMOST does it, except buffer-name is *Minibuf-1*, not what I wanted. I tried (buffer-file-name (other-buffer)), but that gives the OTHER buffer, not the current-buffer before I entered minibuf. Is there other way to get the real current-buffer?

Comment: Nevermind, there seems to be no such function coming with emacs; I'll see if I can hack one.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to fix huaiyuan's solution:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [f3]
  (lambda() (interactive) (insert (buffer-file-name (nth 1 (buffer-list))))))
```

You probably should add some sort of error checking in case the "other" buffer has no file name set and (buffer-file-name) returns nil.

Answer (score 2):

I'll defer to [huaiyuan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455345/in-emacs-how-to-insert-file-name-in-shell-command#455368) about exactly what you asked, but you could also check out [Filtering text through a shell command in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206806/filtering-text-through-a-shell-command-in-emacs) as a possible alternative approach.