# Editing Markdown pipe tables in Emacs

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode

I like to write in Markdown and often find myself needing tables. Are there any good ways of editing Markdown's **pipe tables** in Emacs? I am referring to this kind of syntax:

```
| Header | Header | Right |
|--------|--------|------:|
|  Cell  |  Cell  |  $10  |
|  Cell  |  Cell  |  $20  |
```

I first tried Emacs' [table mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode) which is nice, but is designed for "grid tables" which are not supported by Markdown (let's say in Github's Markdown).

There is also [org-mode's table mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html) which can be used as a minor mode. This comes pretty close; but the intersections are now replaced by `+` characters and there is no support the alignment colon. So `org-tblmode` first gives me something like this:

```
| Header | Header | Right |
|--------+--------+-------|
| Cell   | Cell   | $10   |
| Cell   | Cell   | $20   |
```

which I then need to manually edit to the following (editing intersection characters and adding alignment colon):

```
| Header | Header | Right |
|--------|--------|------:|
| Cell   | Cell   | $10   |
| Cell   | Cell   | $20   |
```

Is there some may that `org-tblmode` can also handle this?
What else do you use/suggest for editing Markdown's pipe tables in Emacs?

Answer (score 11):

OrgMode has nice function `orgtbl-to-generic` for converting orgmode' tables to alien formats. I found simple example defining custom convertor based on `orgtbl-to-generic`: https://gist.github.com/yryozo/5807243. Also see explanation of ORGTBL RECEIVE/SEND features here: http://dynamic-thinking.blogspot.ru/2009/11/orgtbl-mode.html. You need to define custom `orgtbl-to-gfm` function in Emacs and place it to your autoload then you may use minor mode `orgtbl-mode` for editing tables.

Small restriction: only right and left column alignments supported because Emacs OrgMode inside self doesn't supports central alignment.

See above sample org-mode source:

```
<!---
#+ORGTBL: SEND sample orgtbl-to-gfm
| Column 1      | Column 2 |
|---------------+----------|
|               | <l>      |
| Sample line 1 | 100      |
| Sample line 2 | 200      |
-->
```

And the result in markdown converted from the org-mode source:

```
<!--- BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL sample -->
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
|---|---|
| Sample line 1 | 100 |
| Sample line 2 | 200 |
<!--- END RECEIVE ORGTBL sample -->
```

Both them placed in the same file.

Comment: Adding samples was much appreciated.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam I added samples to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I use to deal with tables in markdown mode.  May be
a bit of a hack but works well enough for me. It adds a local
hook to a markdown buffer which, on save, replaces "-+-"
with "-|-" in the entire buffer.

```
(require 'org-table)

(defun cleanup-org-tables ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "-+-" nil t) (replace-match "-|-"))
    ))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'orgtbl-mode)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'cleanup-org-tables  nil 'make-it-local)))
```

Answer (score 10):

`markdown-mode` has the `markdown-do` command (bound to `C-c C-d`). When point is in a table, it pads all the columns so they're aligned.

https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode#usage

Comment: In my case, the TAB key works, too.

Answer (score 4):

Bind the function to a key for a right-aligned conversion of a region:

```
(defun markdown-regexp-right (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (replace-regexp "-\|[^-]" "-:|\n" nil beg end)    
  (replace-regexp "-\\+-" "-|-" nil beg end)
)
```

This will replace `-+-` with `-|-` and replace `-|` with `:|` in the right alignment case.

Note that \n is included, because this makes sure the other `-|-` don't get changed to `-:|`, but only `-|` when it is followed by a `new-line`.

Comment: I appreciate your input but unfortunately when I try this code it crashes Emacs for me :/
With the second line commented out it seems to work, so maybe it is endlessly looping and causing a stack overflow..

Comment: Does it do the job otherwise?

Comment: Oh, and are you calling it on a region?

Comment: Yes I call it on a region, and without the `(replace-regexp "-\|[^-]" "-:|\n" nil beg end)` line it works fine (it just replaces the intersections)

Comment: Anything else that you think should be added?

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce the crash anymore! So your code generally works (although the hyphen before the colon in line 3 should be removed). The larger issue is that this always makes the last column right-aligned, which I don't necessarily always want. I was really hoping for a **generic** way of editing pipe-tables in Emacs..

Comment: Well, how do you have in mind to edit the alignment? Maybe one button to cycle the alignment?

Comment: The problem is that it's not durable. So I can start with an org-mode table and then run this function to convert it into a pipe table. But then if the content length of any of the cells changes, I hit C-c C-c to re-align everything (`orgtbl-mode` shortcut) and it completely messes things up. I was hoping for more of an actual editing mode for pipe tables, but maybe none exists.

Answer (score 3):

Org-mode is so enticingly close that I believe this is a case for its minor mode orgtbl with [arbitrary syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax.html#Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax) to convert. A line containing :-, -: or :-: would thus have its colons removed, and a second line with [`<l>`, `<c>` and `<r>`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment) added to inform org-mode of the alignment. The translation back shouldn't be too hard then. Sadly I'm not good enough at Emacs to write it right now. Incidentally, pandoc's markdown parser does accept + as generated by org-mode.

Having looked a bit more at it, I believe the existing hooks in org-mode require a bit much cruft around the text, and some editing functions are in order. Since this is my first attempt at emacs lisp, my [emacs lisp to convert between orgtbl and markdown](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6430461) is nothing short of horrid, but I have managed to convert a test table.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem as well (I'm a recent emacs convert), and I wrote a little AWK script that can convert the "grid tables" you mentioned (i.e. *not* using org-mode tables) into GFM tables.

There's a couple ways you can use this script. All you have to do is mark the table, then type `C-u M-| name-of-awk-script RET` (I learned this trick from [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206806/filtering-text-through-a-shell-command-in-emacs#207008)). That will use the region as the stdin of the AWK script and replace the region with the output. I'm very much a noob at writing ELisp, but I also wrote a couple of helper functions. The `table-gfm-export` function currently does not replace the text in the same way as doing it interactively with `C-u M-|` would, because it still leaves the original table in the buffer.

```
(defun table-gfm-capture (start end)
  "convert Markdown table to Emacs table
there should be no pipes beginning or ending the line,
although this is valid syntax. Loses justification."
  (interactive "r")
  ;; should prompt user for justification
  (table-capture start end "|"
         "[\n][:|-]*" 'center))

(defun table-gfm-export (start end)
  "uses AWK script to convert Emacs table to
GFM Markdown table"
  (interactive "r")
  ;; replace gfm_table_format if necessary
  (shell-command-on-region start end "gfm_table_format" t t)
  (table-unrecognize))
```

One neat thing about this script is that it can also recognize the justification of the columns using some simple regexes. The other function `table-gfm-capture`, is unable to maintain the justification, so you can't freely switch back and forth. This system is pretty much designed for doing all editing in table mode and then exporting to GFM at the very end. You would Emacs would already have the ability to generate Markdown tables using `table-generate-source`, but alas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
# -*- mode: awk -*-

BEGIN {
    FS="|";
    first=1;
}

function detect_justification(f) {
    if (match(f, /^ .* $/)) {
        return 0;               # center-justified
    } else if (match(f, / $/)) {
        return -1;              # left-justified
    } else { return 1; }        # right-justified
}

function gen_field(len, just) {
    str = sprintf("%*s", len, "");
    gsub(/ /, "-", str);
    if (just <= 0) {
        # left or center, start with :
        sub(/-/, ":", str);
    }
    if (just >= 0) {
        # right or center, end with :
        sub(/-$/, ":", str);
    }
    return str;
}

function gen_rule() {
    str = "";
    # ignore first and last empty fields
    for (i=1; i < NF; i++) {
        len = length($i);
        just = detect_justification($i);
        str = sprintf("%s%s|", str, gen_field(len, just));
    }
    return str;
}

function sanitize_line(line) {
    # strip outer pipes and trailing whitespace
    if (index(line, "|") == 1) {
        line = substr(line, 2);
    }
    sub(/[ |]*$/, "", line);
    return line;
}

! /^\+/ {
    print(sanitize_line($0));
    if (first) {
        print(sanitize_line(gen_rule()));
        first = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Markdown-mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) package provides table support for GitHub flavored markdown.

Markdown-mode is part of Spacemacs (and probably other community configurations).  Note that if using markdown and org layers in Spacemacs, orgtbl will hijack some key bindings, i.e. TAB and format tables using org syntax.  Disabling orgtbl-mode removed the orgtbl highjack.